# Como desativar as Validations ao fazer um Submit no evento change de um DropDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma modal com um dropdown, onde, sempre que for selecionada uma opção, é feito um submit e o modelo é enviado para a action para ser editado e depois é retornado. O problema é que as Validations atrapalham, é possível desativar as validations apenas para o evento change do meu dropdown? O botão Salvar deve funcionar normalmente, mas para o dropdown é necessário desativá-las.

```js
$('#pessoaNatureza').on('change', function (e) {    
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Você pode passar um parâmetro executa validações e fazer dentro do método de submit uma validação para caso o executa validações for true executar, se não passar direto para a requisição http.

`$('#pessoaNatureza').on('change', function (e) {    
  $(this).closest('form').submit(false);
}); `

Comment: Só que em todos os casos eu tenho que dar um submit, só que quando for pelo evento change, ele não valide os campos, isto é, ele deve enviar o form sem validar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela documentação do plugin, você pode *destruir* a instância do validador com o método:

```
validator.destroy();
```

Onde `validator` é o nome da instância do plugin que você iniciou. Exemplo:

```
var validator = $("SELETOR DO FORMULÁRIO").validate();
```

Então seu evento `change` ficaria:

```
$('#pessoaNatureza').on('change', function (e) {    
   validator.destroy();
   $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

O validador será desativado antes do submit e o formulário será submetido no evento `change` do dropdown.

**[Documentação do plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/validator/)**

**Exemplo:**

```js
var validator = $("#commentForm").validate();
$('#pessoaNatureza').on('change', function (e) {    
   validator.destroy();
   $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="./">
   <p>
   <select id="pessoaNatureza">
      <option value="">Selecione...</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
   </p>
   <p>
   <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>
   </p>
   <button>Salvar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado @sam!!!! Funcionou 100% Era isso mesmo que eu estava procurando e não encontrava. Você é fera!!!! :)

Comment: só agora que eu percebi um detalhe: Estou usando o Identity e meu sistema de login é aquele criado automaticamente quando se cria o projeto. A sua sugestão funciona perfeitamente, mas se eu estiver logado no sistema não. Você tem alguma ideia sobre o que isso poderia ser?

Comment: Mais tarde vou pro PC e a gente vê isso blz

Comment: Sem problemas companheiro!!! Quando vc puder!

Comment: A hora que quiser ver é só falar.

Comment: Vi agora sua msg companheiro... Estou on...

Comment: Blz... bora lá. Quando vc está logado o código não "destrói" o plugin? Como é isso?

Comment: Rapaz... é sinistro... Se eu estiver logado, o plugin não é destruído aparentemente. Eu não faço a mínima ideia do que poderia ser....

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80846/discussion-between-jalber-romano-and-sam).